# Showing a function $G$ is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

This is one of the homework questions in an analysis course. The questions goes in the following way. Let Assume that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ the set $A_n$ is countable. In the lectures we have proven that there exists a surjective map $g:\mathbb N \mapsto A_n$.

Prove that the map
$$
G:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \mapsto \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n, G(n,m)=g_n(m)
$$
is surjective.

Now my prove goes in the following way:

First let us look at the codomain of $G$:
\begin{align*}
 \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n = &\{A_1\cup A_2 \cup...\cup A_n\}\\
        = &\{\{a_{1,1},a_{2,1},\cdots,a_{|A_1|,1}\} 
       \cup  \{a_{1,2},a_{2,2},\cdots,a_{|A_2|,2}\} \cup
         ...
         \{a_{1,n},a_{2,n},\cdots,a_{|A_n|,n}\}\}\\
        = &\{a_{1,1},a_{2,1},\cdots,a_{|A_1|,1}, 
          a_{1,2},a_{2,2},\cdots,a_{|A_2|,2},
         \cdots,
         a_{1,n},a_{2,n},\cdots,a_{|A_n|,n}\}\\
\end{align*}
We can now define $g_n(m)$ such that $g_n(m)=a_{m,n}$, meaning the $m$'th element of the $n$'th set. This means that $G(m,n)=a_{m,n}$. For any $a_{m,n}$ we know that $(m,n)$ maps onto that element and we know that $(m,n) \in\mathbb N$ because $m$ and $n$ are both integers, therefore $G$ is a surjective function.$\square$

However I have the feeling that this proof really isn't correct as I'm already defining $G$, however I'm not quite sure. Could someone tell me if something is going wrong and if yes, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written in a more direct way : just take $y \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$. By definition, there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y \in A_{n_0}$. But because $g_{n_0} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A_{n_0}$ is surjective, there exists $m_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g_{n_0}(m_0)=y$. Now, you just have to check that $G(n_0, m_0)=y$ to conclude that $y$ is in the image of $G$, so $G$ is surjective.